# Why the use of both <% and <%= in the views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

If I write something like:

`<% if signed_in?.blank? %>` or `<%= link_to "Sign Up", sign_up_path %>`

What is the difference between the two signs of `<%` and `<%=`?

Why make it this way instead of using just one for simplicity?

When do I know I need to use `<%` over `<%=`?

Comment: If it's not too late, chose HAML: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html or Slim: http://slim-lang.com/docs.html. Both have `xxx-rails` gem to replace ERb in generators.

Comment: Some people actually prefer ERb. While it's worth checking out HAML and Slim, they're not objectively better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<%=` puts the return value of the code inside to the page.

`<%` just execute code.

Here is the good guide about ERB http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html

Answer (score 1):

`<% %>` Simply executes the statement(s) inside that block, whereas `<%= %>` will output the result of the statement.

So for example, with the `<% if signed_in?.blank? %>`, the ruby interpreter just executes that code and checks if `signed_in` is blank.

The `<%= link_to %>` statement will actually generate HTML.